# extract the all the rows before a particular comment for each id -R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the all the rows before a particular comment for each id into a new data frame

```
EID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
comments <- c("apple", "grape", "banana", "rabbit ", "pine", "mango", "banana", "rabbit ", "pine", "apple", "grape", "banana", "rabbit ", "pine")
df <- data.frame(EID, comments)
```

I am trying to extract all the rows in the column(coments) before comment rabbit

expected output:

```
   EID  comments
    1    apple
    1    grape
    1   banana
    2   banana
    3    apple
    3    grape
    3   banana
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try creating a flag for the `rabbit` , filling it and then filter. Here the code using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% group_by(EID) %>% 
  mutate(Flag=ifelse(comments=='rabbit ',1,NA)) %>%
  fill(Flag,.direction = 'up') %>%
  filter(Flag==1 & comments!='rabbit ') %>% dplyr::select(-c(Flag))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   EID [3]
    EID comments
  <dbl> <chr>   
1     1 apple   
2     1 grape   
3     1 banana  
4     2 banana  
5     3 apple   
6     3 grape   
7     3 banana
```

Comment: getting following error could you let me know                                                                                       Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 2 or 1, not size 14.

Comment: @priya Maybe some package issue try `dplyr::filter()`

Comment: Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 2 or 1, not size 14.
i Input `..1` is `==...`.

Comment: @priya Could you share the structure of your data using `str(yourdataframe)`? I suspect it is about the data. Or check if `plyr` was not loaded before `dplyr`

Comment: @priya Looks like comments have different values! Try `unique(yourdf$comments)` and see the values!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` solution that grabs every row before `"rabbit"` by group. This uses `grepl()` with `cumsum()` to filter. Also, note that I used `grepl()` with `fixed = TRUE` rather than `==` because, in your example, `"rabbit "` has extra whitespace.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(EID) %>%
  filter(cumsum(grepl("rabbit", comments, fixed = TRUE)) == 0)
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   EID [3]
    EID comments
  <dbl> <chr>   
1     1 apple   
2     1 grape   
3     1 banana  
4     2 banana  
5     3 apple   
6     3 grape   
7     3 banana
```

Comment: getting following error could you let me know                                                                                       Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 2 or 1, not size 14.

Comment: My guess: it is expecting an index size 2 (in this case, the size of the group that throws the error), or 1 (which it can recycle), but it is getting an index of length 14. Which is odd. Agree with @Duck, seeing the `str()` may help.